# error getting while iterating over two lists in python

Tags: python

I am trying to run the code

```
list = ["ABCD", "LMN" , "STU" , "PQRS" ]

dict = ["ABCD" , "LMN" , "PQRS" ]

for i in list:
 for j in dict:
  if (i == j):
    print(i,j)
  else:
    print(i,j,"No match")
```

Expected output is,

```
ABCD ABCD
LMN LMN
STU No match
PQRS PQRS
```

But as it is comparing i with each value of j ,
Its giving me output as,

```
('ABCD', 'ABCD')
('ABCD', 'LMN', 'No match')
('ABCD', 'PQRS', 'No match')
('LMN', 'ABCD', 'No match')
('LMN', 'LMN')
('LMN', 'PQRS', 'No match')
('STU', 'ABCD', 'No match')
('STU', 'LMN', 'No match')
('STU', 'PQRS', 'No match')
('PQRS', 'ABCD', 'No match')
('PQRS', 'LMN', 'No match')
('PQRS', 'PQRS')
```

i tried with break and continue statements still not getting expected result
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Your printing tuples and doing so in a nested loop on every iteration, why are you expecting that expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You have a nested for loop - as such, you will compare each i in list with every single j in dict.

You could try the following instead:

```
for i in list:
    if i in dict: # checks if the string exists in dict. 
        print(i, i)
    else:
        print(i, "No match")
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are getting tuples instead of strings you hoped. Remove the parenthesis after `print` then you will get what you want.

`print(i,j)` =>`print i,j`

You got twice the expected output because your for loops check every element in the lists twice.

An easier way other than mentioned in the other answer is to use `set` module.

```
A =set(["1","2",.....])
B =set(["2","3",.....])
set.intersection(A,B)
```

BTW, avoid using `list` as your variable name. That is a preserved word.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with filter like this

```
results = list(filter(lambda x: x in dict,list))
```